# Print strings without full stop going onto next line in Python

Tags: python, string

I've had a good look around the site and web and can't find how to do this because its fairly specific, and I've tried everything!

I have a function performing a search and I am trying to print plain-text and strings that are in a particular position in a list.

This is my code:

```
def search_authors( the_author, authors ):

    position = 0

    foundAuthor = False

    for i in authors:
        if the_author in i:
                print((the_author)  + ". (" + str(years[position]) + "). " + str(titles[position]) + ". " + str(journals[position]) + ". "  )
                foundAuthor == True

        #
        #       for some reason this is prnting a dot on the next line, not just after the last entry
        #

        elif position == len(authors) and foundAuthor == False:
                print("not here")
        position += 1
```

This is the output when printed:

```
Anonymous. (1993). Technical correspondance - Random Number Generators. Communications       of the ACM
. 
Anonymous. (1992). Research Directions in Virtual Environments (NSF Invitational Workshop). Computer Graphics
. 
Anonymous. (1998). "Exploring sequential data: Commentary on Bowers, Jentsch, Salas, and Braun (1998)". Human Factors
.
```

I cannot figure out how to stop the last full stop of each search result going onto the next line, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a newline in each element of the journals list.  Try substituting:

```
str(journals[position]).rstrip()
```

for

```
str(journals[position])
```

Comment: Thats worked perfectly, thanks very much for the lightning quick response!!

Comment: If it worked, I'd appreciate it if you could mark the answer as "Accepted" thanks!